# cassandra JMX port

Tags: cassandra, port, datastax

I would like to know if cassnadra uses 7199 port for all the JMX connections / inter node communication? As in earlier versions 7199 was only for initial hand shake but later it uses randomly picking anything between 1024-65355 ports.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you're specifically referring to inter-node communication, take a look at [Configuring firewall port access](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html) in the documentation. It uses port 7000 for inter-node communication, 7001 for SSL inter-node communication, and 7199 for JMX. Note that these docs apply to Cassandra 2.1.X.

Comment: this applies to c* 2.0.x as well